# How to get currently active queryKeys in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I need to invalidate some queries in the `onSuccess` of an `useMutation`.

I have a `queryKey` schema like this:

```
.....
1-["questions", "by_vendor" , "{vendor_code}" , "by_status", "{status}"]
2-["questions", "by_status", "{status}"]
3-["questions",  "by_vendor", "{vendor_code}"]
.....
```

I'm using `useQueryClient` to get the query client.

I need to invalidate the `querykeys` where the `"by_status"` is used.

Is there a way of accessing active `queryKeys`.

There are methods like `queryClient.getQueryData()` but all require the `queryKey` in advance.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at `queryCache.findAll`.

Comment: @super so apparently there's no like a built-in method somewhere, and thank you that works to get the exact queryKeys I did `const queryKeys = queryClient.getQueryCache().getAll().map(cache => JSON.parse(cache.queryHash))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by Chad S. invalidating queries can be done by using objects as the keys, the method will work by a match, it does not necessarily need the exact query to match, and there is a [flag for that](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/filters#query-filters): `exact: true`.

But to get the querykeys, if that is what you are looking for, then here's an explanation.

---

To access the queryKeys that the client is listening to, use the `useQueryClient` hook.

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient()
```

With the hook called, have access to the method: `getQueryCache()`.
This will return the query cache the client is connected to. [Reference](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientgetquerycache)

Now to get the active query keys, call the method `getAll()` in the `queryCache` and this will return an array of `Query`. Now can access the `QueryKey`.

```
const queryCache = queryClient.getQueryCache()
const queryKeys = queryCache.getAll().map(cache => cache.queryKey) // QueryKey[]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest re-organizing your query keys slightly. It is much easier to use objects for keys than using the suggested 'list' style. e.g.

```js
return useQuery(
  ['questions', { by_vendor: vendor, by_status: status }],
  async ({queryKey}) => {
    // Stuff to use the query key and get api data
  }
);
```

Then you can invalidate them later with:

```js
queryClient.invalidateQueries({
  queryKey: ['questions', { by_status: status }],
})
```

For more information check out [Effective React-Query Keys](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/effective-react-query-keys) and [Query Invalidation](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/query-invalidation)